# OpenGL issue while running QML application under RDP

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, rdp, egl

I have developed my application with QtQuick and QML, it works fine with windows and linux, but the application UI doesn't show while connecting to remote peer via RDP, it works fine with VNC.

I have tested it over various configuration, but it never worked over RDP. the error is saying

> createWindowSurface: Could not create the EGL window surface: 0x300e

I think the issue is about opengl but i never used opengl in this application.

My application is based on simple QML applications provided by Qt Quick examples. they're not working too.

Comment: RDP doesn't support OpenGL > 1.1. The only way around this I know of is either starting the app on the physical machine and then connecting via RDP. Or use a different remoting system.

Comment: @rubenvb nothing changed, i've tested it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with Qt's Opengl stack, but normaly it should switch on software mode.

> I think the issue is about opengl but i never used opengl in this application.

Yes, the issue is about OpenGL over RDP, in Qt Quick2 the default backed is native OpenGL backend, so if you developing applications with Qt Quick 2, you need OpenGL driver to.

Try letting QT_OPENGL=software in environment variables, its fixing it temporarily.